# How to move a local bare repository to GitHub

Tags: git, github

I have a local bare repo on my hard disk. I need to move it as is on github. How can I do? Thanks!

Comment: A bare repo? I would personally clone it elsewhere on my local computer, then add github as a remote and then push.

Comment: I done like this. There is no method to do a raw copy - paste from folder to github?

Comment: You've done it? Or you don't like it? If not, why not? Github isn't an ftp. Git has built in tools to achieve what you want. So use them? Take a look at @phd's answer. They even cut out the need for the extra local clone.

Comment: Yes thanks. The problem that I not told was that your method does not copy the tracked branches of the bare repo to the remote repo

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For fetching and pushing (but not pulling) a bare repository contains everything you need to synchronize with any remote repository. Create a repository at Github, configure access (using password or SSH keys), add the repository as a remote to your bare repository and push:

```
cd /path/to/bare-repo
git remote add origin <Github-URL>
git push origin
```

Comment: Many thanks. What about if my remote repo already contains commits and files of another project that I want to delete ? Adding --force to the push will be enough?

Comment: I added --mirror to the push to overwrite all previous content. Thanks!

Comment: You can remove and recreate the repo at Github, then push.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to fully copy everything, including all tags and branches, you can do something like:

```bash
cd my-bare-repo
git remote add origin <github-url>
git push origin --all --tags
```

There is also a `--mirror` option, which does roughly the same as `-all --tags`, but possibly more. It will remove things on the remote side that do not exist locally. I am unsure what other things it pushes, but the man page states:

```
--mirror
    Instead of naming each ref to push, specifies that all refs under refs/ (which includes but is not limited to refs/heads/,
    refs/remotes/, and refs/tags/) be mirrored to the remote repository. Newly created local refs will be pushed to the remote
    end, locally updated refs will be force updated on the remote end, and deleted refs will be removed from the remote end. This
    is the default if the configuration option remote.<remote>.mirror is set.
```